# How can I set up the capability to search uploaded files?

Tags: search

I tried adding a bunch of .csv files to `Site Actions ==>View All Site Content ==>Shared Documents`

Then I typed the name of those files in the `Search this site ...` box but no results popped up.

How can I set up the capability to search uploaded files ?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using. 2010 or 2013, Foundation or Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search is set up in Central Administration of the Sharepoint farm. Assuming that search is set up and running properly, they won't show up instantly as incremental crawls can be scheduled to run at various times.

If you have access to Central Administration, check the Search Settings to make sure there is a search schedule in place and that it is set to index all Sharepoint content. Also note the incremental schedule for search indexing.